# Is there a way to stop this error from popping up? It says expected declaration and I can't get rid of it

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

```
lazy var order = [Int]()
lazy var numbersZeroToFortyNine = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
lazy var FlagNumber: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(49))
for (count) in numbersZeroToFortyNine { // Expected Declaration
        order.append(FlagNumber)
        numbersZeroToFortyNine.remove(at: numbersZeroToFortyNine.firstIndex(of: FlagNumber)!)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I need help with this. I am a beginner, so if there is an obvious answer, please let me know.

Comment: You `for` loop needs to be inside a function, move it to `viewDidLoad` for instance

Comment: Executable code needs to be inside a scope like a function or a closure. That's WHY your for loop won't compile outside of a function.

Comment: @EdgarStu756812 no need to declare your variables as lazy if you property doesn’t need to access `self`. Btw your `numbersZeroToFortyNine` should be just a range `0..<50`